# Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch (matlab)

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

The code is ok for  `input_cell= {'ABC','ACB','BCA'}`

The code can not run for  `input_cell= {'ABC','ACB','BCAD'}`

Can anyone help me to fix this error please?

```
 input_cell= {'ABC','ACB','BCAD'}
 %the code is ok for  input_cell= {'ABC','ACB','BCA'}
 data=[];
for i=1:numel(input_cell)

p=strsplit(input_cell{i},' ')
m=cell2mat(p(:))
m=m-'?'

[~,k]=sort(m);
%compare each pair
M = bsxfun(@(a,b)(a<b)+0.5*(a==b),k,k')
vector = reshape(M.',[],1)  %# Collect the row contents into a column vector
vector = vector' % change from columns into 1 row
data(i,:)= vector  % data matrix inludes all vectors
end
```

Comment: One of your input strings is 4 characters while the others are 3.  I haven't written an answer because I don't know what this code is doing to correct and give you your desired output.

Comment: what does `strsplit` do

Comment: @kgk did you get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by using a struct. In structs the dimensions of each cell can differ.

Comment: The dimension of cell elements can also vary. This is a loosy answer.

Comment: Yes, and it works with structs, since structs holds cell elements.

Answer (score 0):

If your `data` variable can be a *cell*, this works:

```
 input_cell= {'ABC','ACB','BCAD'}
 %the code is ok for  input_cell= {'ABC','ACB','BCA'}
 data={};
for i=1:numel(input_cell);
p=input_cell{i}(:);
[~,k]=sort(p);
%compare each pair
M = bsxfun(@(a,b)(a<b)+0.5*(a==b),k,k')
vector = reshape(M.',[],1)  %# Collect the row contents into a column vector
vector = vector' % change from columns into 1 row
data{i}= num2cell(vector(:,:))  % data matrix inludes all vectors
end
```

Resulting data variable:

```
data = {1x9 cell}    {1x9 cell}    {1x16 cell}
```

hope this helps

Comment: how to see the values of data in your modified code ?

Comment: So _data_ is now a cell array containing 3 cells.  _data{1}_ accesses the first cell and _data{1}(1)_ will index the first element of the the first cell (_data{1}(2)_ accesses second element of first cell, etc).  I don't think MathWorks explains cell array indexing that well, this example from Matlab Central may be a good one to run through:  http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/06/21/cell-arrays-and-their-contents/

Comment: What is your end goal?